# Why this code is showing StackOverflow error?

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class EqualMedian {

    static int median(int[] a, int[] b, int mid, int[] temp) {
        int count = 0;

        if (a[mid] != b[mid]) {
            temp[0] = a[mid];
            a[mid] = b[mid];
            b[mid] = temp[0];

            Arrays.sort(a);
            Arrays.sort(b);
            count++;
            median(a, b, mid, temp);
        }

        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();

        for (int j = 0; j < t; j++) {
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            int a[] = new int[n];
            int b[] = new int[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                a[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                b[i] = sc.nextInt();

            }

            int[] temp = { 0 };
            int mid = (n / 2) + 1;
            int ans = median(a, b, mid, temp);
            System.out.println(ans);

        }
    }
}
```

> OUTPUT: Execution failed. Stack Trace: Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError at
>   java.util.DualPivotQuicksort.sort(DualPivotQuicksort.java:111) at
>   java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:144) at
>   Equal_median.median(Equal_median.java:16) at
>   Equal_median.median(Equal_median.java:19)
>   Equal_median.median(Equal_median.java:19) at
>   Equal_median.median(Equal_median.java:19)

Comment: Do not use `_` in class names use camel case (Java naming conventions)

Comment: If `a[mid]` is never equals to  `b[mid]` the method call itself

Comment: so what can i do?I have to make middle numbers of two sorted arrays equal by swapping number of one array with number of other array.

Comment: Think about and validate your logic

Comment: The logic i have used is that we will swap the middle numbers of two given arrays and sort them.And will repeat this steps until middle numbers of both arrays  become equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your final goal is to determine if 2 arrays have equal median, and if so, print the median? 
You should make a method that computes the median for only one array. Call this method for each array in main. No need for recursion.

```
public static int median(int []myArray) {
    int mid = (myArray.length() / 2) + 1;
    return myArray[mid]
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ...
int firstMedian = median(a);
int secondMedian = median(b);
    if(firstMedian == secondMedian) {
        System.out.println(firstMedian);
    }
}
```

Recursion should not be used without setting proper ending conditions. So.. always double-check your condition. Most recursions have a for/while loop equivalent. If the condition in a while loop sounds like it will go to infinity, it's probably a bad idea.

Also, if a variable can be computed locally and serves no purpose after the method (such as `temp`), don't make it a parameter! Just declare it locally.

Answer (score 0):

You are just swapping the a[mid] and b[mid] and these will never be equal, it will end up in infinite recursive call, so there will be stackocverflow error.

Comment: But then i am sorting both the arrays a[] and b[];

Comment: I have to make middle numbers equal for two sorted arrays.So i came up with a logic that i will swap the middle elements and then again sort them. and if i do this for certain number of times my goal will be achieved.

Comment: @ankit_vd Have you tried it in a pencil test (on paper!)? Just for two small arrays.

Comment: actually this logic worked for some cases on paper but for most cases it failed.